# How can I automatically upload files to my live Server?

Tags: windows-7, file-upload, upload, automation

I am using WAMP for my Local Server in Windows 7. I want to upload my files from a particular folder to my Live Server automatically. Is there any freeware software or anything that will serve my purpose.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WatchDirectory](http://www.watchdirectory.net/download.html) to scan your defined folder and upload only if the file is edited or new file is added to the folder. You can use this for 30 Days trial period.